# Having trouble with for loop range lens question Python

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Im having problem with a for loop word problem.

*You and your friends are traveling to Europe soon. However, it seems like your group has a lot of bags, luggages so you will have to check in some of them at the airport. You look up the airline policy to see what is the maximum weight limit for a bag to be checked in so you don’t make your bag too heavy, which will cost extra. At the same time, you don’t want to check in the bags that are too light and can be accepted as a carry-on to save some money.*

*You want to know which bags your group will need to check in before the trip so you don’t waste time at the airport. You also want to make sure the check-in bags do not weigh more than the maximum weight limit, and not less than the minimum weight that your group can carry onto the airplane. You weigh all bags/luggages and store the results in a Python list called bag_weights.

Define a function get_checkin_bags that takes 3 parameters: a list of numbers named bag_weights, and two floats min_weight, and max_weight. The function should compare each value in the bag_weights list with the minimum and maximum weights allowed (i.e., min_weight and max_weight), and return a list of bag’s weights that are within the weight limits for checking in.*

*You may assume that the min_weight is always less than or equal to max_weight. In other words, the lower limit of weight will always be less than or equal to the upper limit.*

Parameter:

> bag_weights - A list of floats that represents the weights of your
> bags in pounds. min_weight - Minimum allowed weight for a bag to be
> checked in (inclusive) max_weight - Maximum allowed weight for a bag
> to be checked in (inclusive)

Examples:

> bag_weights = [33.0, 6.3, 5.1, 53.4, 31.5] min_weight = 10.0
> max_weight = 50.0 Returns: [33.0, 31.5]

Here is what I have:

```py
bag_weights = [33.0, 6.3, 5.1, 53.4, 31.5]
min_weight = 10.0
max_weight = 50.0

output = []
def get_checkin_bags(min_weight,bag_weights,max_weight):
    for i in range(min_weight, len(bag_weights, max_weight)):
        if bag_weights[i] > min_weight and bag_weights[i] < max_weight:
            output.append(bag_weights)
            return output
```

Problem is when I run it I get nothing and also I am having trouble figuring out where to put min_weight and max_weight, since it says all three should be parameters. I am trying to get what the first example has as return but I get nothing.

Comment: _Problem is when I run it I get nothing_ The code defines a function but never calls it...

Comment: You did not call the function and `print` its returning value, hence no output.

Comment: I guess I was too stressed out trying to figure out what was wrong that I missed one of the most obvious concepts as well. Haha, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You only want to iterate over the bag weights, so you would use:

```
for i in range(len(bag_weights)):
```

However since you then want to access `bag_weights[i]` and you don't really care about `i` otherwise, it's better to loop the values instead:

```
for bag_weight in bag_weights:
```

Full code:

```
bag_weights = [33.0, 6.3, 5.1, 53.4, 31.5]
min_weight = 10.0
max_weight = 50.0

def get_checkin_bags(bag_weights, min_weight, max_weight):
    output = []
    for bag_weight in bag_weights:
        if min_weight <= bag_weight <= max_weight:
            output.append(bag_weight)
    return output

print(get_checkin_bags(bag_weights, min_weight, max_weight))
```

Note also:

- in Python you can do a range check as `min < value < max`
- you should make `output` local to the function, that ensures it gets re-initialised when you call `get_checkin_bags` a second or subsequent time
- you want to append `bag_weight`, not `bag_weights` to `output`
- you have to `print` something to get any output

If you really *need* the index as well as the value, you can iterate over the output of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), for example:

```
for i, bag_weight in enumerate(bag_weights):
    print(i, bag_weight)
```

Output:

```
0 33.0
1 6.3
2 5.1
3 53.4
4 31.5
```

Finally, note that many `for` loops of this type can be written as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def get_checkin_bags(bag_weights, min_weight, max_weight):
    return [bag_weight for bag_weight in bag_weights if min_weight <= bag_weight <= max_weight]
```

Comment: Ooh! That makes sense! So I was in the right direction, well not that far off at least haha. So putting the output outside does make a difference, I thought that putting it outside of the function would not be an issue since I am defining it, but it makes sense since I want it to be part of the function when I call it again and again.

Comment: If I wanted to loop over the index, this means, in this case, it would be an unnecessary extra step right? I could do it, but not necessary right?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but then you would need to specify `bag_weights[i]` instead of `bag_weight`. In general if you don't actually *need* the index for some reason, it's best to iterate just the values. And if you do need the index, you can iterate the index and value at the same time using `enumerate`. See my edit for how to do that

Comment: aah ok, thanks a lot! Enumerate is something that is yet to be covered but I've seen a lot of people use enumerate as well. However, I wanted to get this right before moving on with learning other things.

Comment: @etena_fantom no worries - good idea to walk before you try to run! :)